# How can I create a circular grid in Fortran 90?

Tags: grid, fortran

I have to create a circular grid using the circle equation `x² + y² = 1` with `x` and `y` from `-1` to `1`, increasing `0.1` in each step.

I have tried many different things, but failed, so I would be glad if someone could help me.

One of my attempts was: [attempt one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNOGY.jpg)

```
PROGRAM cir
    IMPLICIT real*8(a-h, o-z)

    real  :: x(20,20), py(20,20), ny(20,20)

    delx = -1.1
    dely = -1.1

    DO i=1,20
        delx = delx + 0.1

        DO j=1.20

            x(i,j) = delx

            ny(i,j)= -1.0 * SQRT ( 1.0 - ( x(i,j)**2 ) )
            py(i,j)= SQRT ( 1.0 - ( x(i,j)**2)  )

            PRINT*, x(i,j), ny(i,j), py(i,j)

        END DO


    END DO

    STOP

END PROGRAM cir
```

And another: [attempt two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgG6O.jpg)

```
PROGRAM circle

    IMPLICIT real*8(a-h,o-z)

    real*8 :: x(20,20), y(20,20), z(20,20)

    delx = -1.0
    dely = -1.0

        DO i = 1, 20
        delx = delx + 0.1

        DO j = 1 , 20
            dely = dely + 0.1
            x(i,j) = delx
            y(i,j) = dely


            z(i,j) = x(i,j)**2 + y(i,j)**2 -1.0


        END DO
        delx = -1.0
        dely = -1.0

        PRINT*, x(i,j), y(i,j)


    END DO

    STOP

END PROGRAM circle
```

Comment: circular grid is pretty vague. What is the type of result you want?

Comment: What do you want as an end result? A boolean array if the points are on the line? They almost never be on the line as you have only some points. A boolean array if the points are inside? The you should have wrote x² + y² <1. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: might be instructive to show what you tried.

Comment: Sorry for my bad question! I'm trying to print the points which belongs to the circle defined by that equation. And these points must be inside the interval -1 to 1, in both axes.

Comment: I added two pictures with codes that I created. I have no previews experiences in Fortran, then I could make mistakes with the use of the language.

Comment: you need to figure out / understand the math you are working with before jumping in and trying to write code.  I still cant figure if you want points "in" the circle or "on" the circle, but there are only four points exactly on the circle on a 1/10 increment grid.

Comment: I want the point in the circle, I mean the points which define the circumference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a really hard time to understand what you want to achieve. At the moment, there are two possibilities:

**Possibility 1:** You want a grid corresponding to values of `x` and `y` in `0.1` increments between `-1.0` and `1.0` that tells us whether this grid point is inside or outside a circle of radius 1.

Here's an example of what such a program might look like, and it's output:

```
program my_circle
    implicit none
    logical :: cir(-10:10, -10:10)
    real :: x, y
    integer :: i, j

    do i = -10, 10
        do j = -10, 10
            x = i / 10.0
            y = j / 10.0
            cir(j, i) = ((x**2 + y**2) <= 1.0)
        end do
    end do

    write(*, '(21A2)') print_cir(cir)

contains

    elemental function print_cir(c)
        ! returns " X" if true, " ." otherwise
        implicit none
        logical, intent(in) :: c
        character(len=2) :: print_cir

        if (c) then
            print_cir = " X"
        else
            print_cir = " ."
        end if
    end function print_cir

end program my_circle
```

Output:

```
 . . . . . . . . . . X . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . X X X X X X X X X . . . . . .
 . . . . X X X X X X X X X X X X X . . . .
 . . . X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X . . .
 . . X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X . .
 . . X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X . .
 . X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X .
 . X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X .
 . X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X .
 . X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X .
 X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X
 . X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X .
 . X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X .
 . X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X .
 . X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X .
 . . X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X . .
 . . X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X . .
 . . . X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X . . .
 . . . . X X X X X X X X X X X X X . . . .
 . . . . . . X X X X X X X X X . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . X . . . . . . . . . .
```

**Possibility 2:** You want a list of x/y coordinates that describe the circle itself. In that case the increment of `0.1`, however, makes little sense, as there are only 3 points per quadrant that are both on your grid and on the circle: (1.0/0.0), (0.8/0.6), and (0.6/0.8).

So for this possibility I have created a little program that prints out a given number (currently 36) of points around the circle, calculating x and y with the trigonometric functions:

```
program my_circle2
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: num_points = 36
    real, parameter :: pi = 4.0 * ATAN(1.0) ! Best way to calculate PI

    integer :: i
    real :: r
    real, dimension(2, num_points) :: cir

    do i = 1, num_points
        r = 2.0 * pi * real(i) / real(num_points)
        cir(1, i) = sin(r)
        cir(2, i) = cos(r)
    end do

    do i = 1, num_points
        write(*, '(I5, 3F8.4)') i, cir(:, i), my_dist(cir(:, i))
    end do

contains

    function my_dist(c)
        ! Calculates the distance of (c(1)/c(2)) from origin
        ! for verification
        implicit none
        real, dimension(2), intent(in) :: c
        real :: my_dist
        my_dist = sqrt(c(1)**2 + c(2)**2)
    end function my_dist

end program my_circle2
```

Output:

```
    1  0.1736  0.9848  1.0000
    2  0.3420  0.9397  1.0000
    3  0.5000  0.8660  1.0000
    4  0.6428  0.7660  1.0000
    5  0.7660  0.6428  1.0000
    6  0.8660  0.5000  1.0000
    7  0.9397  0.3420  1.0000
    8  0.9848  0.1736  1.0000
    9  1.0000 -0.0000  1.0000
   10  0.9848 -0.1736  1.0000
   11  0.9397 -0.3420  1.0000
   12  0.8660 -0.5000  1.0000
   13  0.7660 -0.6428  1.0000
   14  0.6428 -0.7660  1.0000
   15  0.5000 -0.8660  1.0000
   16  0.3420 -0.9397  1.0000
   17  0.1736 -0.9848  1.0000
   18 -0.0000 -1.0000  1.0000
   19 -0.1736 -0.9848  1.0000
   20 -0.3420 -0.9397  1.0000
   21 -0.5000 -0.8660  1.0000
   22 -0.6428 -0.7660  1.0000
   23 -0.7660 -0.6428  1.0000
   24 -0.8660 -0.5000  1.0000
   25 -0.9397 -0.3420  1.0000
   26 -0.9848 -0.1736  1.0000
   27 -1.0000  0.0000  1.0000
   28 -0.9848  0.1736  1.0000
   29 -0.9397  0.3420  1.0000
   30 -0.8660  0.5000  1.0000
   31 -0.7660  0.6428  1.0000
   32 -0.6428  0.7660  1.0000
   33 -0.5000  0.8660  1.0000
   34 -0.3420  0.9397  1.0000
   35 -0.1736  0.9848  1.0000
   36  0.0000  1.0000  1.0000
```

Is either of these what you want?

Comment: That's the second possibility! That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much. I was trying to use just the circle equation to plot these points, but you're totally right: I should use trigonometric functions.